# Providing SQL access to flat file (proprietary) database

Tags: sql-server

We have a "database" that stores historical data in what could effectively be called a highly compressed proprietary "flat file" format.  Typically these are accessed and queried using some C++ code that accesses the files directly.

We would like to provide access to the data to a third party who would like to use SQL queries (e.g. MSSQL).

Are there tools, libraries, or software packages that we can use to present an interface, ideally something that could be connected to using MS SQL Server Management Studio to develop queries that when run, run against our flat file data (short of importing the data into a SQL database).

I have heard rumors of such tools but haven't seen anything yet in practice.

Comment: I doubt it. Why don't you want to import the data into SQL Server? Data belongs in databases - they are specifically designed for this purpose and are (**very much more**) likely to be good at it (**and** retrieving **and** analysing **and**...) than some in-house system/code! p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome.  Performance reasons... we considered it but the throughput performance and compression of flat files couldn't be matched by any DB we evaluated at at the time.  Currently about 1TB/day (compressed).

Comment: Is it IoT time-series type data or what?

Comment: If you have a proprietary database, with proprietary C++ code to read from it, then you'll ultimately need to author an interface (such as a proprietary ODBC driver or REST interface) to create a standard interface that 3rd party tools would know how to make use of

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Use SSIS package registered as a view.
   Downside of this option is that any where conditions are not pushed down to SSIS, so dotNet will have to read all the data. Of course you can create multiple views - like last day only, aggregated values, etc.
   [Walkthrough: Publish an SSIS Package as a SQL View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/walkthrough-publish-an-ssis-package-as-a-sql-view?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. Use a [CLR Table-Valued Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-table-valued-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)
   This way you can pass parameters to underlying dotNet code
3. Use [PolyBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-guide?view=sql-server-ver15).
   This would require a lot of added infrastructure and will allow you to split processing the file to multiple servers (or in Azure).

On the other hand I don't think that compression you are using will be much better than columnstore compression, so I would advise to reevaluate storing this in SQL Server itself.

Comment: +1 on a CLR TVF interfacing with your C++ code.  You'll want to use a dedicated SQL Server instance, in case your native code has memory leaks or cause access violations.